# GroupBy Return Results Outside of Restriction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to include default values for data that is grouped but outside of the where statement.

**Table**

```
Name    Location
-----------------------
Chris   North
John    North
Jane    North-East
Bryan   South
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    Location,
    COUNT(*)
FROM Users
WHERE Location = 'North' OR Location = 'North-East'
GROUP BY Location
```

**Output**

```
North   2
North-East  1
```

**Desired Output**

```
North   2
North-East  1
South   0
```

Is it possible to return a zero for each location outside of the where clause?

**Update**

Thank you everyone for the help. I ended up using the left join as this was quickest for me and produced the correct results.

```
DECLARE @Locations as Table(Name varchar(20));
DECLARE @Users as Table(Name varchar(20), Location varchar(20));

INSERT INTO @Users VALUES ('Chris', 'North')
INSERT INTO @Users VALUES ('John', 'North')
INSERT INTO @Users VALUES ('Jane', 'North-East')
INSERT INTO @Users VALUES ('Bryan', 'South')

INSERT INTO @Locations VALUES ('North')
INSERT INTO @Locations VALUES ('North-East')
INSERT INTO @Locations VALUES ('South')

SELECT 
    l.Name, 
    count(u.location)
FROM 
    @Locations l 
LEFT JOIN
     @Users u on l.Name = u.location and u.location in ('North', 'North-East')
group by 
l.Name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Location,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Location IN ('North', 'North-East') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt
FROM Users u
GROUP BY Location;
```

Or, better yet, if you have a locations table:

```
select l.location, count(u.location)
from locations l left join
     users u
     on l.location = u.location and
        u.location in ('North', 'North-East')
group by l.location;
```

Comment: Your second one is where I was going, but it gives an incorrect result (4 for `North`)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no locations table, the only way to do this is to do DISTINCT and a sub select

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Location,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users AS U 
     WHERE U.Name = Users.Name
          AND Location = 'North' OR Location = 'North-East')
FROM Users
WHERE Location = 'North' OR Location = 'North-East'
```

This code does a lot of table scans and will probably cause your system issues when run on large tables in a production environment where this query would be run multiple times a day.

Answer (score 1):

And a third option, based off @GordonLinoff answer, but giving a correct result is below. This uses a subquery to get a distinct list of locations, and left join's that to the users table.

```
select l.location, count(u.location)
from (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM Users) l 
left join users u
     on l.location = u.location and
        u.location in ('North', 'North-East')
group by l.location
```